# catalog_product.list get storeview product name

Tags: magento-1.8, soap, soap-api-v1

I'm using SOAP to update `META-data` for a specific storeview. Basically I have a localised string where I add the product name to the actual text. However, for some reason I get the default name and not the store specific name. I have added the storeview code `NO` (Norwegian) to the call.

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://www.MY_DOMAIN/api/soap/?wsdl');

$session = $client->login('MY_USER', 'MY_PASS');

$_product = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list', array(),'no');

foreach($_product AS $val){
    echo $val['name']; //Output default name and not storeview name
    $meta_title = 'Köp ' . $val['name'] . ' på minbutik.com ';
    //Update code to follow which work and update
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299663/magento-api-soap-filter-website-ids-error

So:

```
$filters = array(
'filters' => array(
    'status' => 1, 
    'type_id' => 'simple',
),
'storeView' => 'no'
);

$_product = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list',$filters);
```

Comment: Did not help at all. No idea why though. Have solved it temporaily with an ugly workaround where I call product-info using store code and collect it that way instead.